# Rails active job run daily at specific time according to time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have an Active job that is scheduled every day at 3 AM.The application is a SAAS each sub-domain has different time zone. What i'm asking is how to make the background job  runs every 3 AM according to each company's time zone not once at the server time.
I have in my DB the timezone attribute, each company can insert its own.

i have in my sidekiq_schedule.yml

```
schedule_foo_job:
  cron: "0 3 * * *"
  class: "FooJob"
  queue: default
  active_job: true
```

And in the job file

```
class FooJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    DoSomeThing.new.run
  end
end
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with sidekiq_cron ?

I was thinking to make another Job run first to get all the time zones from the DB and get the difference between them and the server time zone then pass each one to the following code

```
FooJob.set(wait_until: "Pass the time here").perform_later
```

But i dont know if that is the best way to accomplish this or not as i will have another timing issue with the running of the first job

Comment: This might help `https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron#time-cron-and-sidekiq-cron`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use rails active record call backs to update the jobs whenever a company is added or it changes it timezone. It will be much more efficient.

On timezone update find job with unique name, destroy it and create new job according to timezone.

You will need to set all the current jobs timezone just once